# Footer showing up different in seperate pages

Tags: wordpress, footer

I am using Wordpress 3.2 with the Weaver Theme 2.0 theme. I have a problem where the footer is appearing different in two different pages. The Home Page (http://putitinorder.com/) is all spread out and slightly shifted to the left. There is also a box around the copyright data at the bottom.

We want this page to look like the About Page (http://putitinorder.com/about-me). I have checked in the back end and everything is the same, they both use the Default template. The Footer info has been added in the Weaver Admin area under Advanced options. I am not sure why it is doing this. I even compared the source code and it looks like it is pretty much the same.

I did take out some of the bottom margins using css because on the home page it was grabbing code from .content h2, h3, p etc. whereas the about page wasn't picking this up.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're missing a closing div on the home page because the footer is getting affected by **#content** while interior is not. About Me has the entire footer surrounded by **#footer** while the home page breaks up halfway through. Check your home page code again and I bet you'll find the missing tag.

The easy way to see what I'm talking about is to inspect a footer paragraph tag in developer tools. Interior will pull up **#footer p** while home shows up as **#content p**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes agreed with austinthedeveloper, you are missing the closing tag for one of the tag inside **#main #container** element on the home page... Check to see in your home page content(MCE html view) if you have closed all the div`s

Comment: I thought so too but if I try just adding a closing div it pushes the footer outside of the container completely, see here: http://putitinorder.com/. This is an older site and there aren't any actual divs or unclosed spans in the content of the home page. Would the homepage be using a different template than the default even if it says it is using the default template? I tried changing this to a full width template but nothing changed.

Comment: You might want to check index.php or some of the other template files in case the template has been duplicated. Whatever page Home has been set for usually uses index.php and you can't change the template.

Comment: check your template file populating home page, its is certainly a markup issue. Theh home page can be font-page.php, home.php or index.php depending on your reading settings under General. To get to the file that is being used try understanding this as per your theme files: http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

Comment: I have tried to find it but when I bring up the source code for both the home page and the interior page they have the exact same number of opening and closing divs in pretty much the same places. Any other suggestions?